# create a project in Maverics using ARC on 32 bit

Tags: objective-c, cocoa

I am creating a project in maverics(using xcode 5.1.1) ,for 64 bit its running fine but for 34 bit it is giving error.
while running on 34 bit getting this error "-fobjc-arc is not supported on platforms using the legacy runtime"

to remove above error disabled ARC,but i need ARC also

so is there any way to create a project in Maverics using ARC on 32 bit

Comment: @downvoter please give reason for downvote

Comment: because you read the documentation: https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/64bitPorting/indications/indications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001064-CH206-TPXREF101 which says ARC is supported for 64bit on OSX *only*

Comment: yeah i know,but my requirement is like that.....m jst asking is there any way to develop

Comment: What's a point to make 32-bit app? All modern mac's is 64 machines.

Comment: @deshu Unfortunately not, the intent of only delivering ARC for the more modern objective C run-time was deliberately to push developers to writing 64bit applications. Apple has a track record for this - e.g. [Carbon never came on 64bit](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Carbon_(API)).

Answer (score 1):

The 64-bit transition guide for OSX states [quite clearly](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Darwin/Conceptual/64bitPorting/indications/indications.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40001064-CH206-TPXREF101) that ARC on OSX is **only** supported on 64bit.

> Applications that target OS X v10.7 and later should take advantage of automatic reference counting (ARC). This technology frees you from having to manually retain and release objects, and in so doing, often fixes latent bugs in applications.
>
> ARC is supported only in the new Objective-C runtime, which is supported only in 64-bit applications. For this reason, most new development should be 64-bit.

Comment: It's whacker from Apple. Not all knows that ARC performed in compile time. It's just add `retain` and `release` calls for you. So there is no technical difficulty to add ARC in 32-bit environment. But they just denied it for 32-arc, because they want make you develop only 64-bit applications. Btw. ARC is possible on 32-bit IOS applications.

Comment: @Cy-4AH the modern objective C run-time appeared on iOS before it appeared in OSX, and that's what's needed to support ARC. And as iOS started supporting arm64 in XCode 5, while supporting ARC for iOS before that it would be necessary for it to support it on the 32 bit run-time